# Get id from url in react.js

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I just want to make Ajax request to fetch data from API in REACT.JS, but every API need (id), I want to get that id from URL in browser, how can I do that?

This is my code:

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/personal/1")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        information: json,
    })
})
```

I make the API by Laravel, and every thing work good with this code above, but as I said, I want to get the id from url in browser not just write it as now, thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can make use of the `history` prop from `react-router-dom`, here is a link that explains how to do so in detail,

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

**Approach #2**

If you want to make it super simple, then how about making use of the `window.location` object?

Suppose you are on a page with the url `http://localhost:8000/personal/1`

`window.location.href` would give `http://localhost:8000/personal/1`

`window.location.pathname` would give `/personal/1`

Once you have the `pathname` or `href` you can use your regular string functions like `split(...)` and get the ID.

Comment: Approach #2  works if you can not use hooks, Thank you

Answer (score 44):

In React Hooks, You should use `useParams()`.
ex - This is your url - `http://localhost:8000/personal/1`.

So in this case, use `const { id } = useParams()`

now, if you do `console.log(id)`, it will give you the exact id of the url. In this case, it will give you 1.

useParams() extracts the id from the url and lets us use it.

Comment: useParams is from the react-router library and your route should be appended with /:id so you can access the value using "const id = useParams();"

Comment: import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

Answer (score 10):

In your Route you can specify a parameter and then later get that with useParams.

```
// App.js
<Route path='/post/:id' component={PostDetail} />

// Single post component
import axios from "axios";    
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// Get ID from URL
const params = useParams();
    
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(()=> {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/posts/${params.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setPosts(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }, [params.id])
```

From there on out you can use {post.yourdata} in the component.

Answer (score 6):

First of all in your navigation file like app.js or navigation.js add this route

```
<Route path="/home/:id"  element={<Landing />} />
```

than on the Landing screen or page use this code to obtain that value

```
  const params = useParams()
  console.log(params)
```

Answer (score 4):

**For hooks user**

```js
import React from "react";
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductDetails = () => {
const {id} = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Product id: {id}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Answer (score 3):

In Class Component you can access ID by adding `constructor` and then access ID from `props` for example

```
export class PostDetail extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
      placeholder: "Loading"
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(<h1>Post Detail</h1>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

remember useParams is from react router dom not from react package

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use [rect-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) if you are using react for the front end. That way you can easily manipulate path parameters and access them in you components using `match.params.[paramName]`.

By using plain js you could use `window.location` object.

- `http://localhost:8000/personal/1 => window.location.pathname =
  personal/1` [path params]
- `http://localhost:8000/personal?id=1 =>    window.location.search =
  ?id=1` [search params]

If you are using search params there's a good library called [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) to parse them. And of course if you are using path name you'll need to manually strip out you params.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class components in React, you can use:

`this.props.match.params.id`

this will get the `id` from the url.